# How can I solve float to string since I'm working with a function

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm practicing python and I've encountered an error with string to float error. My intention is to give a function as an input, where I can put ^ as an indicative of **. Then, the 3d graph, related to the function, will be shown. I've searched for the string to float error, but since my function need to have special characters, the solutions didn't work for my case.

```
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

funciao = []
func = input("Enter your function: ")
function = func.replace('^','**')

def fun(x,y):
    return function

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x,y) for x,y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Comment: `zs` is just going to be an array of strings, `[x**x,x**x,..]`

Comment: Solved based on my comment, let me know if you have any issues

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
import sympy
import numpy as np
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import random

funciao = []
func = input("Enter your function: ")
function = func.replace('^', '**')


def fun(x, y):
    in_dict = {
        "x": x,
        "y": y
    }
    subs = {sympy.symbols(key): item for key, item in in_dict.items()}
    ans = sympy.simplify(function).evalf(subs=subs)

    return str(ans)


fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.05)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
zs = np.array([fun(x, y) for x, y in zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y))])
Z = zs.reshape(X.shape)

ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z)

ax.set_xlabel('X Label')
ax.set_ylabel('Y Label')
ax.set_zlabel('Z Label')

plt.show()
```

Now `fun()` will actually return the correct numerical string values, rather than `function` which is just the string you entered for the function. It does this by subbing in `x` and `y` into the formula using `sympy`.

Note: You will need to install `sympy`, and the math for this in high definition will be very slow. So be prepared to wait a while for a graph to appear.

Consider changing this line `x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.01)` to `x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5)`. Which will generate the data much quicker (resolution from `0.01` to `0.5`).

---

You can also define `zs` in a `tqdm` loop to see the progress bar:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm

# ...

zs = []
for x, y in tqdm(zip(np.ravel(X), np.ravel(Y)), total=len(np.ravel(X)),desc="Calculating data"):
    zs.append(fun(x, y))
zs = np.array(zs)

# ...
```